# using Simple html DOM to extract id

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm using simple html dom to extract a users fantasy football team. What I'm trying to do is get the "id" number for each player in the source code below. So for example in the div below the "id" is 121.

```
<div id="ismGraphical1" class='ismPitchElement  {"coptr": null, "played": 0, "pos": 1,           "can_sub": 1, "ep_this": 4.5, "event_points": 2, "id": 121, "sub": 0, "m": 1, "copnr":   null, "is_captain": false, "team": 6, "is_vice_captain": false, "type": 1, "ep_next": 4.5} '>
```

The code below returns the entire div, but I want to get the id only. I've tried using a nested for loop, but it's not working. I think it has something to do with the array inside the div. But not sure where to begin. If anyone could point me in the right direct I would be grateful

```
$html = new simple_html_dom($result);
foreach($html->find('div.ismPitchElement') as $pitchview)
echo $pitchview;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No external library is required. You can use `DOM` and `XPath`, these classes are part of the PHP core:

```
$result = <<<EOF
<div id="ismGraphical1" class='ismPitchElement  {"coptr": null, "played": 0, "pos": 1,           "can_sub": 1, "ep_this": 4.5, "event_points": 2, "id": 121, "sub": 0, "m": 1, "copnr":   null, "is_captain": false, "team": 6, "is_vice_captain": false, "type": 1, "ep_next": 4.5} '> 
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($result);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($selector->query('//@class[starts-with(., "ismPitchElement")]') as $classattr) {
    // remove the prefix using `ltrim()`
    $json = json_decode(ltrim($classattr->nodeValue, "ismPitchElement"));
    var_dump($json->id);
}
```

Output:

```
int(121)
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that

Comment: Have updated the answer. Can be done with less code as you see.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to do it using simplehtmldom lib that much.

```
foreach ($html->find('[class^=ismPitchElement]') as $el) {
        print json_decode(ltrim($el->{'class'}, "ismPitchElement"))->{'id'};
    }
```